# How to set the child divider to the default theme color in expandable list view

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I want to set the child divider color to the default theme color.

I have removed the child dividers using

```
 expandableList.setChildIndicator(null);
 expandableList.setGroupIndicator(null);
 expandableList.setDividerHeight(2);
```

Now, I want only the last child divider to have the divider and that too, it should have the default theme divider color.

So, in the group_child.xml, I have added a view as follows:

```
  <View
    android:id="@+id/divider_child"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.5dp"
    android:background="#FF0000" /> <------ How can I change this color to the default theme  divider color
```

Is there the possibility to set the view > android: background color to the default theme color? How can I do that?

Comment: just replace #FF0000 with your default theme  divider color may be avoiding  android:background="#FF0000"  will help you

Comment: How to do that?  Where can I find the theme divider color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have the default theme divider color

```
android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"/>
```

Comment: @Vishnu: I think this is a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AppCompat theme, then you need to refer the color attribute to the background as follows

```
 <View
    android:id="@+id/divider_child"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.5dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
```

in your `getChildView` method write the condition as follows

```
     if (childPosition == getChildrenCount(groupPosition) - 1) {
        convertView.findViewById(R.id.divider_child).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  
     } else {
        convertView.findViewById(R.id.divider_child).setVisibility(View.GONE);
     }
```

Comment: Thanks, using android:background="?attr/colorPrimary", the color is not the same.. it seems to be darker, I am using AppTheme